# Changing the disk type of vsphere VM using Rest API

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, disk-image, web-services

I am looking for a way to convert my Vsphere VM disk type using REST API calls, like "Dependent" and "Independent-Nonpersistent".

i was searching in the documentation for Sphere 6.7,could not find a way to perform this operation
Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

There is no REST API for ESXi but there *was* a partial one for vCenter, looks like it's been discontinued but here's the link to its documentation if it's any use (https://github.com/vmware-archive/vsphere-automation-sdk-rest).